# How to create specific plots using Pandas and then store them as PNG files?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot, histogram

So I am trying to create histograms for each specific variable in my dataset and then save it as a PNG file.

My code is as follows:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
x=combined_databook.groupby('x_1').hist()
x.figure.savefig("x.png")
```

I keep getting "AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'figure'"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `matplotlib` to create a figure and axis objects, then tell `pandas` which axes to plot on using the `ax` argument. Finally, use `matplotlib` (or the fig) to save the figure.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Sample Data (3 groups, normally distributed)
df = pd.DataFrame({'gp': np.random.choice(list('abc'), 1000),
                   'data': np.random.normal(0, 1, 1000)})
```

---

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
df.groupby('gp').hist(ax=ax, ec='k', grid=False, bins=20, alpha=0.5)
fig.savefig('your_fig.png', dpi=200)
```

#### your_fig.png

[image]

Comment: This is the approach I would take. You can also call `savefig` directly on the object e.g. `fig.savefig('your_fig.png')` if you wish to avoid using both oop and state-machines

Comment: Hi, I tried entering this code but it says fig not defined.

Comment: I finally got it to work. You are right I did have a typo. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `*.hist()` I would use `matplotlib.pyplot.hist()`.

Example :

```
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

y =[10, 20,30,40,100,200,300,400,1000,2000]
x = np.arange(10)
fig = plt.figure()
ax = plt.subplot(111)
ax.plot(x, y, label='$y = Values')
plt.title('my plot')
ax.legend()
plt.show()

fig.savefig('tada.png')
```